# Read word from file into 2d string array

Tags: c

I have words separated by \n in a file:

```
Moscow
Berlin
Lisbon
Amsterdam
Paris
Nairobi
```

I want to read these words into 2d string array.
But when I want to suppress any term of the series, I can't get results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define K 10

int
main()
{
    int i,j;
    char c;
    int count=0;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("input1.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("file not found\n");

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            count++;
    }

    char chz[count][K];
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        for (i=0;  i<count;  i++) {
            for (j=0;  j<K;  j++) {
                fscanf(fp,"%c",&chz[i][j]);
                if (chz[i][j]=='\n') {
                    break;
                }
            }
            chz[i][j]='\0';
        }
    }
    printf("%c",chz[0][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

There may also be more city names in the file.So I calculated the number of words in the file in the first place.How can I fix this problem?Thanks...

Comment: After the first `while(fgetc())` loop, the file is at the end.  `feof` will (most likely) return true, and the second loop iterates zero times.  The only way that loop is entered is if there was a read error, in which case it is an infinite loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you very much for your response.I solved the problem by adding Fseek.But there's one more thing I'm stuck with.Why, for example, when we type chz[3][20], it prints a character.doesn't adding '\0' to the end of the array solve the problem?

Comment: You need to do `rewind(fp)` after the `fgetc` loop. Otherwise you are already at EOF for the next loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `rewind(fp)` after the `fgetc` loop. Otherwise, you're already at EOF for the next loop.

Why do `fscanf` in the second loop instead of `fgetc`?

You don't add an EOS character at the end of each string.

Your second loop can be simplified. Note that you rely upon the fact that each line ends with `'\n'`. So, given that, you don't need to check against `count` in the second loop. You could add that as a cross check but it's really not [absolutely] necessary.

Here's a refactoring of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define K 10

int
main()
{
    int i,j;
    char c;
    int count=0;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("input1.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("file not found\n");

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            count++;
    }

#if 1
    rewind(fp);
#endif

    char chz[count][K];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while (1) {
        int chr = fgetc(fp);

        if (chr == EOF)
            break;

        // add EOS to "previous" word and start a new word
        if (chr == '\n') {
            chz[i][j] = 0;
            ++i;
            j = 0;
            continue;
        }

        // append char to word
        chz[i][j++] = chr;
    }

#if 0
    printf("%c",chz[0][1]);
#else
    for (i = 0;  i < count;  ++i)
        printf("WORD: '%s'\n",chz[i]);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

You assume that the word length will never exceed `K` (i.e. `K` is fixed).

But, since you're looping through the file to calculate `count`, you can just as easily *calculate* the maximum value for `K` at the same time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{
    int i,j;
    char c;
    int count=0;
    FILE *fp;
    int len;
    int K = 0;

    fp = fopen("input1.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("file not found\n");

    len = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            if (len > K)
                K = len;
            count++;
            len = 0;
        }
        else
            len++;
    }

#if 1
    rewind(fp);
#endif

    char chz[count][K + 1];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while (1) {
        int chr = fgetc(fp);

        if (chr == EOF)
            break;

        // add EOS to "previous" word and start a new word
        if (chr == '\n') {
            chz[i][j] = 0;
            ++i;
            j = 0;
            continue;
        }

        // append char to word
        chz[i][j++] = chr;
    }

#if 0
    printf("%c",chz[0][1]);
#else
    for (i = 0;  i < count;  ++i)
        printf("WORD: '%s'\n",chz[i]);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> But I have one last problem. When I try to print this expression as `chz [i][j]` some words end up with meaningless signs like `^ +%`. How can I prevent this?

You didn't post your code for this, but I suspect that you were using two nested loops, such as:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < count;  ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < K;  ++j)
        printf("%c",chz[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Not all strings are the same (i.e. maximum) length. The probable reason is that, for strings that are shorter than `K`, you were outputting the extra [garbage] characters.

You need to stop at the length of each individual strings. Here's an adjusted set of loops to do that:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < count;  ++i) {
    int j = 0;

    while (1) {
        int chr = chz[i][j++];

        // stop at end of word
        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        putchar(chr);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thank you very much. But I have one last problem. When I try to print this expression as chz [i] [j] some words end up with meaningless signs like ^ +%. How can I prevent this?